# User Authentication with MVC 5, without EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I am trying to upgrade an old asp.net app (not the Database), to an MVC 5 application. I've select to use Individual account authentication, and cant seem to find a way of decoupling, the EF requirements. Not sure if it even possible, but how can one use ASP.NET Identity without the overheads of EF?

What is everyone else using?

Comment: You can use plain old Forms Authentication if you want to. You'll just have to wire it all up yourself.

Comment: Hi Sam, i'd like to take advantage of the Claims, can this be achieved using Forms Authentication?

Comment: Sorry, I've only used traditional Forms Authentication with roles. Don't know how claims fit in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide an own implementation of the `IUserStore<TApplicationUser>` interface. Then update the generated default constructor for the `AccountController` to use your own implementation instead of the default EF based one.

Comment: Anders, can you direct me to any documentation, i'm relatively new to this, and want to fully grasp your suggestion. Cheers

Comment: There some good stuff written by @OdeToCode at http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/25/asp-net-core-identity.aspx.

Comment: Ok Anders, you've led me to some serious reading :-) One question I have. Having spent the last couple of hrs researching the above site, am I correct in assuming that I need to roll all my database table (none user related) into then EF model? The reason I ask, is that I want to register and authenticate a user, but then use Dapper to provide data back to my MVC app, plus to a mobile app via Web Api 2. From some example from Scott, he seems to roll everything into the same localDb, which i don't want to do if possible

Comment: You don't have to roll everything into the same db, nor do you have to use EF. Your own `IUserStore<TApplicationUser>` implementation can store the user info where and however you want.

Comment: Ok, so i've create an instance of UserStore and UserManager. How, do I now ensure the UserManager.Create write to my already existing Users table, and not EF?

Comment: Did you change the generated default ctor for `AccountController`? That's where the implementation to use is set.

Comment: I started from fresh, so didnt use an MVC app, reverting back to WebForms.

Comment: any examples you could point me too Anders. the documentation seems limited to none existent. :-)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Can you share the source code if you did? I'm currently trying to write Asp.Net.Identity.Dapper

Comment: @Robert Thanks for commenting, but the way Stack Overflow works follow up questions should not be posted as comments, but rather as a new question with a link back to this Q.